# Target specific dropdown css from shinywidget package

Tags: css, r, shiny

I'm struggling to find out how to target 1 of the two dropdowns specifically with css styling code. 
I can style the dropdowns in general, but not individually

I have tried to target it in the following ways, but none work.

```
#MyDropDown1 .sw-show.sw-dropdown-content {       

#sw-content-MyDropDown1 .sw-show.sw-dropdown-content {

.dropdown-content-MyDropDown1 {

#dropdown-content-MyDropDown1 {

#dropdown-menu-MyDropDown1 {
```

How to find the right syntax to target the 1st dropdown?

here is the app:

```
  library(shiny)
  library(shinyWidgets)

  ui <- fluidPage(

    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
     .sw-show.sw-dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    left: 200px;
    top: 100px;
height: 300px;
width:
    } '))),

    dropdown(inputId = "MyDropDown1",
             tags$h3("List of Input")),
  dropdown(inputId = "MyDropDown2",
           tags$h3("List of Input"))
  )
  server <- function(input, output, session){
  }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: `#sw-content-MyDropDown1` is the correct id. It is not enough to set the css ?

Comment: No, it doesn't overwrite the shinywidgets css unfortunately

Comment: As an update, my way to work was wrapping the shinywidget "dropdown(...)" in a tags$div(class="test, hereThedropdown() ). Then in the css, I just added the line ```.test {background-color:"#FFFFFF"}``` .  And this added into the dropdown the features I wanted.  ```tags$div(class="test,  dropdown(inputId = "MyDropDown2",
           tags$h3("List of Input")) ) ```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a way to go. But unfortunately because of the margin I end up with 2 boxes...
But at least the css style apply only on the first dropdown

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(

    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
                              .test {
                              display: block;
                              background-color:red;
                              left: 200px;
                              top: 100px;
                              height: 300px;
                              width:
                              } '))),

    dropdown(inputId = "MyDropDown1",
             tags$h3("List of Input"), class = "test"),
    dropdown(inputId = "MyDropDown2",
             tags$h3("List of Input"))
    )
server <- function(input, output, session){
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: still haven't managed to make this do more than create a strange effect... I'll ask the author of shinywidgets again

Comment: could you post or add the link to your question to the author, please?